# Spring JPA Throws "Unknown entity" exception

Tags: java-8, spring-data-jpa

Jdk 1.8.0_82, Springboot 1.3.8 and JPA.

I want insert new rows made from existing object value.

I Just call

```
List<LogSchemaFieldModel> newFields = Lists.newArrayList();
for(LogSchemaFieldModel f : fields){
newFields.add(new LogSchemaFieldModel(){{
                        setFieldName( f.getFieldName() );
                        setFieldType( f.getFieldType() );
                        setFieldOpt( Field.Mode.NULLABLE.toString() );
                        setDescription( f.getDescription() );
                        setSampleValue( f.getSampleValue() );
                        setCommon(true);
                        setRequired(null);
                    }});
}
repo.save(newFields);
```

but it throws this exception.

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Unknown entity: com......service.LogDefineService$6; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown entity: com......service.LogDefineService$6
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:384) ~[spring-orm-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:227) ~[spring-orm-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:436) ~[spring-orm-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59) ~[spring-tx-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213) ~[spring-tx-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147) ~[spring-tx-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:131) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.9.5.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208) ~[spring-aop-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy119.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.my...
```

Answer (score 5):

finally, I found solution.

remove double brace initialize.

```
List<LogSchemaFieldModel> newFields = Lists.newArrayList();
for(LogSchemaFieldModel f : fields){
LogSchemaFieldModel nf = new LogSchemaFieldModel();
                nf.setFieldName( f.getFieldName() );
                nf.setFieldType( f.getFieldType() );
                nf.setFieldOpt( Field.Mode.NULLABLE.toString() );
                nf.setDescription( f.getDescription() );
                nf.setSampleValue( f.getSampleValue() );
                nf.setCommon(true);
                nf.setRequired(null);
newFields.add(nf);
}
repo.save(newFields);
```

But I don`t knwow why it works.
is it java8 double brace initialization bug?

Comment: Had same issue. Removing double brace initialisation solved it for me. Does anyone know why this is an issue?

Comment: I had to the problem with Spring boot and H2 database